# How to select data with array value on where clause with ajax - codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter, where-clause

I have a multiple select in my view named `categories[]` that contain the values of `id` on my table. I want to get the value from that `categories[]` and make a where clause with it : `Where id = categories[] selected values`. but, it is an array. How I can set the Where clause with array value? So I can get the data Where the id have the selected value from `categories[]`

I have 3 column in my table :

`(id, category, name)`.

The values of my table is :

```
(1, "food", "Pizza")
(2, "food", "Burger")
(3, "drink", "Mineral Water")
(4, "drink", "Tea")
(5, "snack", "Apple Pie")
```

What I've do is : get the selected value by making this command in my view :

```
var v = $('[name="categories[]"]').val();

//and doing like this, so I can get it to my controller
"data": 'cat=' + v,
```

Then, I get the selected value in controller like this:

```
public function getData(){
   $cat = $this->input->post('cat');
   $where = array('id' => [$cat]);
   $result = $this->my_model->getData($where);

   //and some code to set the data in my table
   //and code for return the data
}
```

And finally, I set the WHERE clause in my model like this :

```
public function getData($where){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from($this->table);
   $this->db->where($where);

   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->resut();
}
```

The way I've done above yield query like the following :

```
Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT `id`, `category`, `name` FROM `my_table` WHERE `id`= Array ORDER BY `category` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL you need is `WHERE IN` and the query would look like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (12,14,55,346);
```

In your first function, make sure $cat is an array

```
public function getData(){
   $cat = $this->input->post('cat');
   if (!is_array($cat)) $cat = explode(",", $cat);
   $where = array('id' => $cat);
   $result = $this->my_model->getData($where);
}
```

Then use where_in() in your model

```
public function getData($where){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from($this->table);
   $this->db->where_in($where);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
}
```

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: I just corrected a typo in case you were getting errors - inArray() should have been in_array() - and implode() should have been explode() - corrected

Comment: Hi, acctually. I was confused till now. I get the array from categories right, but I'm confuse, how can I get the array data in my controller? I've tried to get with this `$cats = $this->input->post('cat');` but when I'm trying to `echo $cats`, It return null value

Comment: and also, when I'm trying to check the value of `var v` by make an alert that contain `var v` value, it display the right array value. `ex : 5,2,7` as the value that I choose

Comment: in your controller funciton, put in a `if ($_POST) var_dump($_POST);` line to see what you're getting through post. Sounds like the cat variable is called somethign different or missing

Comment: could you please check this question? I think the problem that cause my value is null is because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496628/how-to-pass-data-on-ajax-to-codeigniter-controller