# how to pass data on ajax to codeigniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, controller

I have a select option. I want to pass the selected option value to my controller from ajax. But, I got the value is null when I'm trying to echo it from my controller (so I can see the value).

this is how I display my select option :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#">
    <select name="categories" onchange="ipilihCat()" id="categories" class="js-example-placeholder-single form-control" style="width: 200px;">
        <option value="">pilih category</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($cats as $cats) {
            echo '<option value="' . $cats['category'] . '">' . $cats['category'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

here is the ajax code that I use :

```
function ipilihCat(){
var selected = $('#categories').val();

$('#target').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order": [],
    "ajax": {
        "data": {
            'cats': selected
        },
        "dataType": 'json',
        "url": "<?= base_url('welcome/iselCats'); ?>",
        "type": "POST",
        "success": function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    },
    "columnDefs": [{
        "target": [-1],
        "orderable": false
    }],
});
}
```

And in my controller, I check it like this :

```
public function iselCats(){
   $cats = $this->input->post('cats');
   echo $cats;
}
```

I think there is a problem when I pass the data from ajax.
I this the right command to pass the data?

```
"data": {
            'cats': selected
        },
```

Comment: what is `selected` here ?

Comment: hi, thanks for responding my question. I have updated my question. it is from `var selected = $('#categories').val();`

Comment: That code is called on load ? If yes your select-box will have 1st option as selected which has `value=""`.

Comment: where is your ipilihCat() defined??

Comment: I set the select option with this `onChange = ipilihCat()` and the **function ipilihCat()** contain the ajax code

Comment: I have updated about the ipilihCat() in my question

Comment: Dear it is datatables it can not work like this, datatables make ajax request onload of page obvious it will send the value of select empty, what you want to accomplish please can you explain it, as per i understanding you want to filter the table as change in select value?

Comment: @munawarhussian yes, I want to filter the table as change in select value. So when the selected value change, the table will be filtered as the selected value

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line in your code

```
$('#target').DataTable({
```

to

```
var table = $('#target').DataTable({
```

and add the following code

```
$('#categories').on("change",function(){
    table.ajax.url( "<?= base_url('welcome/iselCats'); ?>?cats="+this.value ).load();
});
```

this will send the cats to your server and refresh the table and the rest of the filtering code will be handled serverside manually

Answer (score 0):

Try with the change below, have used it a couple of times.

```
"url": "<? echo base_url('welcome/iselCats'); ?>",
```